# PowerBuilder Datawindow (report) shows momentarily then disappears on retrieve

Tags: powerbuilder, datawindow

We have a report that is designed to look like a two page form. Upon making changes needed by legal for the 2018 version of form **the report shows momentarily after retrieve but then disappears**. If you retrieve repeatedly it flickers and you can see the report but that's all.

**Specifics:**

- Freeform datawindow.
- Contains many computed fields with autosize-height, shift directly above enabled
- Font size is mostly Arial Narrow size 9
- Logo at top of report.
- Designed to take exactly two 8.5 x 11" pages.
- PowerBuilder 11.5.1 Build 5097 on Windows 7
- Print Preview mode off
- Header,Footer,Summary bands are not used
- Detail band has height autosize-height turned on
- Detail band in development mode is at about 18" and the maximum a column or text extends right is about 7.75"
- Reduced print margins to 80 all around, Portrait, Paper size 8.5 x 11"

**Things tried and/or hints:**

- If we insert a row into the datawindow (simulates adding a new contract) the datawindow report shows up fine and we can scroll from top to bottom.
- The datawindow control is resizable with no border and is sized so that width accommodates the report but height requires scroll. Tried turning live scroll off/on with no changes
- Experienced something similar in past, where inserting a row, then immediately deleting that row causes the "blanked" rows to show up. This solution works on tabular style datawindows with multiple rows.
- Doing GroupCalc() after the retrieve as it sometimes solves odd things like this.
- Resizing the datawindow control and re-retrieving while running app.

If anyone has solution, or suggestions on what to try please advise.

Comment: I understand that if it shows information and then disappears it may be because the dw has a filter that runs at the end of the retrieve.

Comment: Possibly a filter- there shouldn't be one there- but worth checking- thanks.

Comment: Just a few more to your checklist. 1. Size and type of your columns in dw vs those returned in resultset. 2. Try retrieving from dw designer. 3. Any errors in Dw while retrieving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering myself- the problem wasn't one that you'd typically think of.

The datawindow querymode was turned on in PFC inadvertently causing the behavior.

Simply turning off the querymode solved this.